# random access arrays in Makefile

Tags: makefile

i want to write a Makefile which execute command with two input from two different array
for example

```
a = A B C
b = 1 2 3

./run A 1
./run B 2
./run C 3
```

i don't know how to write it because there is no way to access array index in Makefile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Space-separated lists can be pretty much treated like arrays using [`$(word n,text)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html):

```
./run $(word 1,$(a)) $(word 1,$(b))
./run $(word 2,$(a)) $(word 2,$(b))
./run $(word 3,$(a)) $(word 3,$(b))
```

To avoid repeating yourself you could define a helper like this:

```
run-cmd = ./run $(word $1,$(a)) $(word $1,$(b))
```

And then generate your commands like so:

```
$(call run-cmd,1)
$(call run-cmd,2)
$(call run-cmd,3)
```

Another way is to use this thing I coded a while back:

```
list-rem = $(wordlist 2,$(words $1),$1)
pairmap = $(and $(strip $2),$(strip $3),$(call \
    $1,$(firstword $2),$(firstword $3))$(call \
    pairmap,$1,$(call list-rem,$2),$(call list-rem,$3)))
```

This `pairmap` takes a function name as first argument and two space-separated lists as second and third. It calls the function for each zipped pair from the two lists.

Then you can define a helper like this:

```
run-cmd = ./run $1 $2;
```

And `$(call pairmap,run-cmd,$(a),$(b))` will generate `./run A 1;./run B 2;./run C 3`.